# Add note to emails in Mail App or alternative Mail app?

Tags: macos, mail.app, email

I just found http://www.indev.ca/MailTags.html but I will not pay 30 bucks just for adding some notes to my mails.

Are there some free extensions or alternative mail apps that support adding notes to emails?

That would be awesome. I searched a lot but didn't find a good alternative.

The point is: I want to add a simple comment/note on my mail so I directly can identify the state (e.g. 'waiting for response with data')

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just found [Nylas N1](https://www.nylas.com/n1), an email client built open source and web-based. Has already a tagging feature and more but you can easily extend anything you want with JS-Skills. In future there should be a plugin for everything.

Answer (score 2):

[Mailmate](http://freron.com) allows extensive [tagging](http://manual.mailmate-app.com/organize#tags) (IMAP compatible). A very good mail client, btw.

Comment: Sadly not free..

Answer (score 1):

Depending on how simple you need your notes, flags might cover what you need.
Apple Mail allows you to put a colored flag on your mail by right-clicking it (you can add it to the menu bar as well). As soon as you start flagging mails there will be a view besides/under your inbox which organizes them by the different flags.

Comment: I tried it, but that was too unclear.. but thanks ;)